# How to execute a standard java script job after a Dataflow pipeline job, packaged in servlets?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow job packaged in a servlet (a runnable working in `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` mode and triggered daily by a CRON job (in AppEngine).

I can't managed to execute some Java script when the pipeline is DONE. It works when launching locally with Jetty but not when deployed with AppEngine.

What is the best way to do such a task ?

---

EDIT : this is the error I get. Basically I try to sink first data into Cloud Storage and then perform a BigQuery Patch then load in a standard java code.

In the logging this is what I can find after Dataflow Logs (though I cannot see any "Stopping dataflow workers" logs, that is weird...) :

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93) at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.getJobWithRetries(DataflowPipelineJob.java:351) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.getStateWithRetries(DataflowPipelineJob.java:323) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.waitToFinish(DataflowPipelineJob.java:236) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.waitToFinish(DataflowPipelineJob.java:191) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:117) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:56) at ... at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ... 20 more`

Any ideas ?

---

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "Java script" as in java code that runs in your AppEngine servlet, not Javascript on the client browser side.

What happens when you launch on App Engine? I'm concerned that the servlet is only open for the duration on an HTTP request, so if you have a long job then your servlet could timeout. Perhaps AppEngine closes the thread in this case. Do you have any error log, stack trace, logging when before and after running the pipeline, etc.?

Comment: I edited my question with the logs I managed to retrieve thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception seems like the servlet is timing out. I think that the HTTPRequest can only be held open for a couple of minutes before the timeout occurs. So I don't think its safe to block after running the dataflow job in the servlet code.

Can you launch the process and wait on another thread in the servlet? Then build some sort of mechanism to have your client keep polling the servlet until the dataflow job is done. (You may need to have the client store an identifier/token to identify the running job).

Alternatively you can use DataflowPipelineRunner (which does not block), and return the job id on the HTTPRequest.

Then you can keep polling the servlet until the job is done, by using the DataflowClient you can keep checking the job until its status is no longer RUNNING, i.e. FAILED or SUCCESS.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineDebugOptions#getDataflowClient--

This getjob call in DataflowClient can be used, given the job ID. 
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowClient.java#L89